# yargs is throwing a ExperimentalWarning

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, yargs

I am writing a node.js CLI program and for some reason when I just include `yargs` like

```
const yargs = require("yargs");
```

I get a warning:

```
(node:30562) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

I'm not sure why and it's pretty annoying to see every time I test my application. Any idea why this warning is appearing and how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think a newer Node version may resolve this. See https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31845

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running into the same thing and asking over here https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1763

EDIT: Update your node version. It is fixed when you upgrade. I verified on node --version v14.11.0